# ASP.NET MVC Model Validation per deployment

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, deployment

If have a product developed with asp.net and MVC that is being used by multiple customers, how can I have different model validation per deployment. Say in 1 scenario a field is required and another it isn't, or a max length is 10 in one and 15 in another?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [validationattribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.aspx), and load those on demand depending on your client